# emacs: leaving buffer in terminal emacs

Tags: buffers, emacsclient, terminal-emacs

After opening a file with `emacsclient -nw foo.txt` I see

```
When done with a buffer, type C-x #
```

in the minibuffer.

I however habitually do `C-x C-c` instead of `C-x #`

Is there a practical difference between the two?

Comment: Did you mean `C-x C-c`? `C-x C-x` exchanges mark and point.

Comment: you're right my typo

Comment: What did the doc tell you about the difference?

Comment: I didn't browse the docs, I don't know how to ask the docs this question

Comment: @joshsverns you can ask what a key does by typing `<F1> k` and then the keybinding you're interested in.

Comment: my Mac has no F1 key )-:

Comment: In that case use `C-h k` instead, unless you've rebound the help prefix.